# Remove char \ from string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone help me replace this char?

```
    varrr = trecov.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    varrr = varrr.replace("3D", "")
    varrr = varrr.replace("=\r", "")
    varrr = varrr.replace("\n", "")
    #varrr = varrr.replace("\", "").strip() <- Cant seem to get this one working
    trespon.insert("1.0", varrr)
```

Can someone help me remove the \ from the string?

Comment: you need to escape it `"\\"` or call it literal `r"\"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `\` that is do

```
varrr = varrr.replace("\\", "").strip()
```